# How to enter get-childitem in to a string

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am tring to create a script that will output the name of .txt files via for loop that counts the number of files and creates an option to open .txt file from just one click.

```
$s = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\*.txt -Name | Measure-Object -Line).Lines

for($i=0; $1 -gt 5 ;$i++)
{
    $c = [string[]](Get-ChildItem -Path C:\*.txt -Name)
    [void] $objListBox.Items.Add('$i')
    Write-Output $c
}
```

I am stuck with Get-childitem like in $c to get the list of file names into a variable so i can split or get the line for user option.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to add to the listbox each txt file name in C: drive?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements. Where does `$1` come from? `'...'` strings are _verbatim_ strings, so `$i` in `'$i'` is _not_ expanded.

Comment: What is the reason for this ***(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\*.txt -Name | Measure-Object -Line).Lines***? You want to pull the file FullName in order to open it. You can display just a short name on the buttons, but you must pass the FullName. You can also do this without creating a form at all, by doing this with Just ***Out-GridView***;  $TargetFile = (Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' -Filter '*.txt' | Select-Object -Property Name, FullName | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title 'Select a file to review');Invoke-Item -Path $TargetFile.FullName, that is if you don't require a fancier WF/WPF GUI.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what exactly you want from the script,
but here is my approach to set the items in $objListBox

```
$txtFiles=Get-ChildItem -Path C:\stackoverflow -Recurse -Filter *.txt 

#Option 1 FullPath to Items
$txtFiles.fullname | ForEach-Object { $objListBox.Items.Add($_) }
#Option 2 Just the Name to Items
$txtFiles.name | ForEach-Object { $objListBox.Items.Add($_) }
#Option 3 Just the Name without Extentension to Items
$txtFiles.basename | ForEach-Object { $objListBox.Items.Add($_) }

#Count for All Files
$txtFiles.Count
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-6.0)
method to convert any given object to a string. If you want $c to be a string, the code you are looking for would look something like this:

```
$c = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\*.txt -Name).ToString
```

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis on your method. ;-)

Comment: You forgot "option to open .txt file from just one click."

Answer (score -1):

Made a form for you that is created with a dynamic size and additionally a scrollbar if there is no space left. buttons that start the txt file and close the form. More comments in the code.
[image: Example screenshot of form]

```
$basePath = "C:\"
$SearchString = Join-Path $basePath "*.txt"
$filenames = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchString -Name | Sort)
$count = $filenames.count

#All you need for System.Windows.Forms to work
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Variables for generating size
$ButtonHeight = 35
$ButtonWidth = 450
$WindowTitle = "Choose a file"
$BottomSpace = $StartHeight = 10
$LeftSpace = $RightSpace = 30
$CurrentHeight = $Startheight
$FormHeight = 60 + $BottomSpace + $StartHeight + $ButtonHeight * $count
$FormWidth = 20 + $LeftSpace + $RightSpace + $ButtonWidth

# Create the form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = $WindowTitle
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($FormWidth,$FormHeight)
$form.FormBorderStyle = "Fixed3d" # Sizeable: User may change size - Fixed3d: User may not change size
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.AutoScroll = $True # Scrollbars when you need it
$form.Topmost = $true #always on top
$form.MaximizeBox = $false #Allows to maximize window

# Generate the buttons in a foreach and arrange them
foreach ($filename in $filenames) {
    $GeneratedButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $GeneratedButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($LeftSpace,$CurrentHeight)
    $GeneratedButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($ButtonWidth,$ButtonHeight)
    $GeneratedButton.Text = $filename
    # Action to take when button is clicked -- Open file and close form
    $GeneratedButton.Add_Click({ Start-Process (Join-Path $BasePath $this.text) ; $form.Close() })
    $form.Controls.Add($GeneratedButton)
    $CurrentHeight += $ButtonHeight
}

# Activate the Form when loaded
$form.Add_Load({
    $form.Activate()
})
# Show the form when loaded, but hide any results
$form.ShowDialog() > $null  # Trash any output
```

Comment: Point of Note: As posted, your code does not open the file of each button. It will just open the same file no matter which button is selected.

Comment: No worries. It happens.  ;-}